# why css overflow hidden not working in this case

Tags: css

I want to disable scrolling on `.content` div . and only enable scrolling on .nav div if it overflows ..

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:60px 1fr;
}
.header {
  background:white;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:10;
  box-shadow:0 2px 4px grey;
}

.content {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:200px 1fr 250px;
}

.nav {
  background-color:white;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

CodePen Link : https://codepen.io/chandu0101/pen/dyyQEaR

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question, not a third party site please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div`s will automtically expand to fit their content. Give `.content` a height or `max-height` and it will stop expanding.

```css
.content {
  overflow:hidden;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:200px 1fr 250px;
  height: 200px; /* <-- */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.content` will have the height of it's children, but forcing it to have a specific height, it will do what you want, just add `height: 80vh;` or whatever height you want, to your `.content` class

Comment: i think you mean `.content`

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't defined height to you `.nav`, then it would heighten as much as it needs to. In order to limit the height, you could set it a fixed height (in the code below, it equals to the maximum height minus the header height). This way, you won't even need `overflow-y: scroll` since it would be redundant.

Add a fixed height to your nav:

```
.nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```